# Use Go modules with incompatibilities together fabric-gateway fabric-sdk-go

Tags: go, hyperledger-fabric

I want to use the features of two Go modules, but one of the Go modules was not updated in a while. The prototypes definition might have drifted apart and I get panics while trying to reload the definition a second time. I was able to turn the panics into warnings, but still I fear problems. What are the options to consume such modules together? Is there something like individual compilation units which can be still be woven together

The modules I'm using are [fabric-gateway](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-gateway) and [fabric-sdk-go](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go).

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are hitting is that the legacy [fabric-sdk-go](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go) API uses Fabric protocol buffer bindings built using the deprecated [github.com/golang/protobuf](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/golang/protobuf?tab=overview) API, whereas the newer [fabric-gateway](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-gateway) API uses Fabric protocol buffer bindings built using the newer [google.golang.org/protobuf](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/protobuf?tab=overview) API. Using both in the same application means that you have two bindings for the same Fabric protocol buffers, generated from the same protocol buffer definitions. This results in a [protocol buffer namespace conflict](https://protobuf.dev/reference/go/faq/#namespace-conflict). I don't know any way of allowing the two to coexist within the same application.

If you are using the legacy fabric-sdk-go API only for chaincode deployment or channel configuration, you might be able to use [fabric-admin-sdk](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-admin-sdk) instead. This uses the same protobuf bindings as fabric-gateway (and actually also uses fabric-gateway internally) so both can coexist within the same application.